# fetch yahoo email details using OAuth c#

Tags: c#, oauth, yahoo-api

In my windows form application,trying to fetch details of yahoo email such as sender,date,subject,body text & attachments. I'm using OAuthBase.cs class to get request and access token. 
Now my issue is to fetch users e## Heading ##mail details. For contact details i used :

```
"https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/"+ yahoo_guid +"/contacts?format=xml");
```

From the above i got all contacts of user with email. Now i couldn't find the request Url for email's details. Any kind of help will be much helpful to me.

Thank in advance.

Comment: OAuth is for auth, not fetching emails.  Can you be more specific? I.e your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: By OAuth we can fetch emails information also as we do for gmail.I just want to know that is der any uri or endpoint available by which i can get emails headers or details??

Comment: Emails aren't fetched "using OAuth" with gmail either.  You authenticate with OAuth and then the gmail API that fetches email has access to the inbox you want.  Sounds like what you're really asking is "how to fetch email from yahoo".

Comment: But based on the url you posted, it looks like you want to get the contacts, not email

Comment: Url posted above is exactly for contacts and i mentioned it, now how i can fetch emails of same user ??